# How to intercept all key events sent to an editable NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a hidden NSTextField that i want to capture all key events sent to it when it is the first responder and redirect those key events to another NSView. I have tried different ways to listen to the key press, but all of them seem to not prevent NSTextField to handle the key events.

I did this for accessibility reason. We have our own custom text field UI. There seems to be no way to make voice over treat it as text field unless you are using a real NSTextField. Therefore, I have to create a hidden NSTextField to interact with the macOS and send key events to our own custom view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSTextField - notifications when individual keys are pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308985/nstextfield-notifications-when-individual-keys-are-pressed)

Comment: No It does not, controlTextDidChange is called AFTER the text has been changed, I want to be able to intercept and ignore key event depends on what key is pressed. I actually figured out how to do that, I will post a answer shortly

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383196

Comment: Ah yes, that is basically the solution i found as well, it is not upvoted as the answer and I overlooked. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself.

The solution is not perfect, but it fits my use case. The trick is to insert your own field editor for the NSTextField.

When NSTextField becomes the first responder, the NSWindow will ask its delegate to return a custom field editor. You will need to implement `NSWindowDelegate` selector [windowWillReturnFieldEditor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419416-windowwillreturnfieldeditor?language=objc). In this method, you can return your own NSTextView as a custom field editor (return nil will make NSWindow to use the default field editor). Once you implemented the `NSWindowDelegate`, you can attach it to your window by doing myWindow.delegate = myCustomWindowDelegate.

Now your NSTextField will use your NSTextView as its field editor. To intercept the key events, you just need to override the keyDown/keyUp selector in your NSTextView to do you own logic. The downside of this approach is you won't have access to the default implementation of the field editor, you need to wire up the entire text editing logic on your own.